# Sorting files based on the number in them

Tags: python, sorting

I am having few files like..

```
l.1,l.3,l.2,l.12,l.36,l.24
```

When i am sorting the list it is giving me...

```
l.1,l.12,l.2,l.24,l.3,l.36
```

How can i get them in this way?..

```
l.2,l.2,l.3,l.12,l.24,l.36
```

Note: because it is not permitting to add the actual file name as it is i ve given it as a list. but the actual file names are joined by '.' like l.1 l.2

I can write a bubble sort algorithm for that. But I want a simpler way..
Thanks

Comment: Are those `1`s (the number) or `l`s (the letter)? Also, is it a list of numbers, a list of strings, or one big string?

Comment: Search for Python natural sort; e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort

Comment: sorry  tobias_k its letter 'l's not the digit '1' s :P

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
  l =  ['l.1','l.3','l.2','l.12','l.36','l.24']
  sorted(l, key = lambda x: int(x[2:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In one line:

```
>>> li = ["l.1", "l.3", "l.2", "l.12", "l.36", "l.24"]
>>> sorted(li, key=lambda x: int(x.split(".")[-1]))
['l.1', 'l.2', 'l.3', 'l.12', 'l.24', 'l.36']
```

Comment: can u please tell me how to list files in a directory matching a sepcified string with out a for loop in a line :)

Comment: Filter your list first (e.g. `li = [x for x in li if "somestring" in x]`), then proceed as given above. If it's a complex pattern you want to match, use regex.

Comment: thanks i m implementing it now but just want to check any inbuilt function available. Thank you so much

Comment: Johannes it is returning me an error because my files are lsb.acct.1.. like that

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Python documentation the sort function on a list takes multiple argument ([relevant section here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)).

You can use the `key` argument to specific a function which gets the key. An implementation for you case could be:

```
def key_fn(n):
    return int(n.split('.')[-1])
```

You could then do:

```
l = ["l.1","l.3","l.2","l.12","l.36","l.24"]
l.sort(key=key_fn)
```